# Application of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I want to apply [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to a function $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$ to discuss the situation when $x\to -\infty$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is integrable. But in the statement of the theorem, the sequence of measurable functions is countable and $n\to +\infty$. Do I need to set another function $h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}f(t)dt$ and the characteristic functions to be $\chi_{[-\infty,-n]}(t)f(t)$to apply the theorem? Or I can apply the theorem directly to the original function $g(x)$?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(t)f(t)dt$, where $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(t)=1$ for $t\leq x$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $|\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(t)f(t)|\leq |f(t)|$. So, you can use $f$ as the master, and $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(t)f(t)$ as the slave.

Comment: Observe that, for each fixed $t$, $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(t)f(t)$ tends to zero, when $x\to-\infty$. In fact, it is equal to zero as soon as $x$ becomes $<t$.

Comment: @acetone Why do we need $x$ becomes $<t$? Isn't $x$ independent of $t$?

Comment: It is not so much as needing it, it is that you have eventually it, since $x\to-\infty$.